# How to scale background image

Tags: css, background, split, size, scale

I have a site I am working on, where I would like a background, with white in the middle and another color like black on the sites. I have made a code like this.

```
body { background-color: #000000; background-image: url('BackgroundImg.png'); }
```

Now my problem is that the background image streches, to fit the whole screen, where I only want it to be in the middle, with a specific width size. How do I scale the background image to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code gives you centered image with no repeat , you can adjust position by giving position

```
 body {
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url('BackgroundImg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center; }
```

For size adjustment:  replace size-x, size-y with image size manually

```
 body {
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url('BackgroundImg.png')size-x,size-y;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-size` and `background-position` properties.